# Extract int value in index array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have a question about this score table I made in html.

```
var puntenTelling= new Array(3,4,2,1,5);
var teamNamen = new Array(puntenTelling[0]+"Team1", puntenTelling[1]+"Team2",puntenTelling[2]+ "Team3", puntenTelling[3]+"Team4", puntenTelling[4]+"Team5");
puntenTelling.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
teamNamen.sort();
teamNamen.reverse();

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><td>" + teamNamen[i]);
  document.write("<td>" + puntenTelling[i] + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Basically this gives me a sorted table, which is sorted on points, and sorted on the teamnames linked to the points.
I have to include the points (puntenTelling) in the array of the teamNames since otherwise I can't sort it in the same way I can sort the points.

Now I am printing it out like this:

```
Teamname  Points
5Team5       5
4Team2       4
3Team1       3
2Team3       2
1Team4       1
```

I would just like to get rid of the "5,4,3,2,1" 
before the "Team5,Team2" etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of concatenating points and team names is not very clean and robust (how about a team named `1860 Munich`?) Much better would be to make an array of objects that contain both team name and its points, and work with this array:

```js
var teamsWithPoints = [
    { name: "team1", points: 3 },
    { name: "team2", points: 4 },
    { name: "team3", points: 2 },
    { name: "team4", points: 1 }
  ];

teamsWithPoints.sort(function(a, b) { return b.points - a.points });

document.write("<table>");
teamsWithPoints.forEach(function(team) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + team.name);
  document.write("<td>" + team.points);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're making the array, you're creating objects like this.

```
var teamNamen = new Array(puntenTelling[0]+"Team1", puntenTelling[1]+"Team2",puntenTelling[2]+ "Team3", puntenTelling[3]+"Team4", puntenTelling[4]+"Team5");
```

If you don't want the value to be included in the string value, you'd declare `teamNamen` like so.

```
var teamNamen = new Array("Team1", "Team2","Team3","Team4","Team5");
```

However, this will make your original sort not function properly. So you could try this following code to maintain the proper sorting functionality, while printing the correct value.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><td>" + teamNamen[i].substring(1));
  document.write("<td>" + puntenTelling[i] + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: I know, but I have to otherwise my TeamNames won't be sorted the way the points are. They are interconnected.

Comment: Omg thanks. Btw it's like this: teamName[i].substring(1)

Comment: Oh woops, mixed those up. No problem!

Comment: Simple solution yet for some reason I couldn't find it. Thanks again!

Comment: @georg This is a solution assuming this is the only type of data needed. In reality, a dictionary system would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need a dictionary (associative array) where the keys represent the team's order in the list. Sort the array by the keys, then just print the values. It could even be multidimensional where the key is the desired ranking position and the value contains the team name and the points.